# How to limit drush tar-options="--exclude pattern matching to be specific and not recursive

Tags: drush, backups

With the folder structure like so
`/site_root
/site_root/images
/site_root/core
/site_root/core/modules/images
/site_root/libraries`
etc

When doing a drush archive dump backup, from the inside `site_root` (usually it's `public_html` but in this case it's another folder), I use
`$ drush ard tar-options="--exclude=images" --destination=~/.backups/[date].tar.gz`

That way the archive dump skips the /site_root/images folder and the ard is much smaller.
Unfortunately for me pattern matching then causes all `images` folders throughout to be excluded due to recursivity.
So I would lose
`/site_root/images`
`/site_root/core/modules/images`
etc

I know in linux you can make `tar-options` look at the folder structure by making the pattern relative, like so
`$ drush ard tar-options="--exclude=./images"`
But that is not working for me via `drush ard tar-options`.

I also tried the home folder shortcut `'~'` (which works a treat on `drush ard destination`) like so
`$ drush ard tar-options="--exclude=~/site_root/images" --destination=~/.backups/[date].tar.gz`
But, for some reason, that does not work like it does on the `–-destination` switch.

What is the best way to limit the `drush tar-options="exclude` switch to either no-recursive or pattern match looking at relative path to working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you can use the current working directory, as the starting point, to force relative urls. It was a matter of getting the syntax correct.

For example if you have your site root in `public_html`, and you are in that location `cd ~/public_html`, you can use drush:

`[user public_html]$ drush ard tar-options="--exclude=public_html/images" --destination=~/.backups/[date].tar.gz`

The key is to navigate to that starting point root folder first.

For example, if your site root was in a subdirectory `subdirectory/siteone`,
 go to that location first `cd ~/subdirectory/siteone`
and then use drush:

`[user siteone]$ drush ard tar-options="--exclude= siteone/images" --destination=~/.backups/[date].tar.gz`